# Is a pointer to an array of unknown size incomplete?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

3.9/6 N3797:

> [...]
>
> The type of a pointer to array of unknown size, or of a type defined
>   by a typedef declaration to be an array of unknown size, cannot be
>   completed.

It sounds like a pointer to an array of unknown size is an incomplete type. If so we couldn't define an object of a pointer to array of unknown size. But it is not true, because we can define an array of unknown bound.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int (*a)[] = (int(*)[])0x4243afff;

int main()
{

}
```

It compiles fine.

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c055a33b64bd424)**

We could't do it if it were incomplete type. Indeed:
3.9/5:

> Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type

The Standard previously defined an incomplete types as follows 3./5:

> A class that has been declared but not defined, an enumeration type in
>   certain contexts (7.2), or an array of unknown size or of incomplete
>   element type, is an incompletely-defined object type.
>   Incompletely defined object types and the void types are incomplete
>   types (3.9.1).

Which means the pointer to an incomplete type is complete. Contradiction?

So where I'm wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Why do you think you can't have a pointer to an incomplete type?

Comment: ever written a linked list struct like "typedef struct list { void *value; struct list *nxt; } list"?

Comment: That's no array. that's just a memory address.

Comment: @BadZen We **can** declare a pointer to an incomplete type I know it. Could you read my question more attentively?

Comment: @C_Plus_Plus_Programmer The Standard said the type of a pointer to array of unknown size couldnot be completed. Which means that type is incomplete, right?

Comment: "Which means the pointer to an incomplete type is complete" - precisely what I'm saying.  There is no contradiction.

Comment: @BadZen But it contradicts to a definition of an incomplete type given in 3.8/5. I cited it in my updated question.

Comment: @BadZen May I don't understand what the Standard means in there... Could you clarify?

Comment: A pointer type, that "points" to an incomplete type, is a complete type itself. However, we cannot change the type of `int (*a)[]` to, say, `int (*)[5]`. This is, I think, what the Standard wants to say with "cannot be completed".

Comment: @BadZen I think you misread, it says "The type of a pointer to array of unknown size ... cannot be completed". Therefore the type *of a pointer* etc. is incomplete. It is saying that `a` in Dmitry's code has incomplete type (not `*a`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb But if it were saying that then `sizeof(a)` would be ill-formed, and it isn't. I think dyp's explanation makes the most sense. The wording in the spec is a bit confusing though, and could probably be improved to be more clear.

Comment: Is `a` really an array? http://ideone.com/UDC6kh seems to think it isn't.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Nobody said `a` is an array, but `*a` is an array of unknown size.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG `decltype(*a)` is a *reference* to an array (of unknown size). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03688d54cf8925f7

Comment: If you want to quote the standard, at least get your section number right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this wording is defective. In your code:

```
 int (*a)[];
```

the type of `a` is actually complete. The type of `*a` is incomplete. It seems to me (as dyp says in comments) that the intent of the quote was to say that there is no way that later in the program, `*a` will be an expression with complete type.

Background: some incomplete types can be completed later e.g. as suggested by cdhowie and dyp:

```
extern int a[];
int b = sizeof a;  // error
int a[10];
int c = sizeof a;  // OK
```

However `int (*a)[];` cannot be completed later; `sizeof *a` will always be an error.

Comment: Wording like "given a pointer to an array of an unknown size, or a typedef declaration to be an array of an unknown size, the array type cannot be completed" would probably be an improvement in clarity.  (Though it could probably still use some wording tweaks.)

Comment: And, to provide an example to readers, what we mean by "cannot be completed" in this context is that you cannot give the size of the array later.  For example, given a declaration `int a[];` this type is incomplete but *can be completed* -- you can specify `int a[10];` later to complete the type.  But given the declaration `int (*a)[];` you *cannot complete type of `*a` later* -- `int (*a)[10];` would be an error.  `*a` is doomed forever to have the incomplete type `int[]`.

Comment: @cdhowie I think `extern int a[];` might be better, since it's a legal declaration.

Comment: @dyp Indeed, I was thinking more about the types themselves than the validity of declaring them bare. It's too late to be thinking about this stuff. :X

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have misunderstanding about "completed to" concept. The type `A` is completed to `B` later on means the declaration `extern A a;` and definition `B b`; declare and define a variable of the same type. Right?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv yes, and also that the type of `a` is `B` at any point in the file after `B` was defined

Answer (score -1):

Like C++ statements, English sentences must be interpreted *in context*. The context of the quoted sentence makes its meaning perfectly clear. The paragraph reads (§3.9 [basic.types]/p6, the sentence you quoted is bolded):

> A class type (such as “`class X`”) might be incomplete at one point in
>   a translation unit and complete later on; the type “`class X`” is the
>   same type at both points. The declared type of an array object might
>   be an array of incomplete class type and therefore incomplete; if the
>   class type is completed later on in the translation unit, the array
>   type becomes complete; the array type at those two points is the same
>   type. The declared type of an array object might be an array of
>   unknown size and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation
>   unit and complete later on; the array types at those two points
>   (“array of unknown bound of `T`” and “array of `N T`”) are different
>   types. **The type of a pointer to array of unknown size, or of a type
>   defined by a `typedef` declaration to be an array of unknown size,
>   cannot be completed.**

Read in context, it's clearly saying that a "pointer to array of unknown bound of `T`" can't be "completed" into a "pointer to array of N `T`" in the way that an object declared as an "array of unknown bound of `T`"" can be later defined as an "array of N `T`"

Comment: *"The context of the quoted sentence makes its meaning perfectly clear."* Guessing from the previous questions of the OP, I'd assume that the OP knows that context but didn't understand that sentence nevertheless. Also, that quote doesn't tell us whether the pointer type itself is incomplete.

Comment: Well it is obviously an issue about understanding what "completed" means here. If I complete something, it has been incomplete before, but that kind of incompleteness is not the same as the one defined in 3.9/5. I do think that this is confusing, at least a bit. I do not think that the context in 3.9/6 *clearly* points out this difference.