# Pointer to array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

Consider the following cases:

1.

```
extern int *a;
int *a = new int(1); //OK
```

2.

```
extern int a[];
int a[5]; //Ok
```

3.

```
extern int (*a)[];
int (*a)[5]; //error: redefinition of 'a' with a different type: 'int (*)[5]' vs 'int (*)[]'
```

Could you explain why 3rd case throw a compile-time error? What exact deffirent from previous two? I'm looking for a corresponding reference to the Standard.

Comment: Have you tried to do `extern int (*a)[5]`? There is a trick with the empty `[]` that sometimes are saw as another pointer, so your code maybe is interpreted as `extern int (**a)`.

Comment: Just wondering, given a declaration `extern int (*a)[];`, what does your compiler give as `sizeof a` and `sizeof *a`? I have a vague feeling that at least one of these two expressions will not compile because it tries to take the size of an incompletely declared object.

Comment: But this is just what you've asked about earlier: The type of `a` cannot be completed. That's in the quote of [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25967060).

Comment: @dyp That is in the 3rd case I have that the first and the last declarations declare varibles of different types.

Answer (score 1):

In Short:
The 3rd scenario is different because, the **type** of the pointer variable mismatches - the extern declares a pointer to an array of ints with an unknown size(incomplete type), and the definition is for the same variable, but as a pointer to an array of 5 ints, which are different (valid) types according to the standard.

Detailed:

The first scenario is staightforward:
the extern int* a only declares the existence of a variable of type int *.
the second line defines the same variable.

the second scenario:
 I read through the standard again, and this is what it says:

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown size
>   and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and
>   complete later on; the array types at those two points (“array of
>   unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types

I believe what this means is that the definition of the array with a subscript **completes the previous declaration** of the variable as an array with unknown size(no subscript) - this is what is happening in scenario 2.

the third scenario:
Using the same meaning as from the standard, **the array types at those two points are of different types**.
Hence case 3 fails, because the first and second declarations would then be declaring the same pointer variable as pointer to different types, leading to a "redefinition with different types" error

[Edited answer after re-reading the standard]