# Formal understanding of the complete type concept

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand that concept formally. Section 13/1 says:

> two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with
>   **different types** are called overloaded declarations. **Only function** and
>   **function template** declarations **can be  overloaded**; variable and type
>   declarations cannot be overloaded.

That formally means, for example that programs contains the following:

```
extern int a[5];
int a[6];
```

are ill-formed because of the types `int[5]` and `int[6]` are different.

Now consider the declaration

```
extern int a[];
int a[6];
```

The standard says that 3.9/6:

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown size
>   and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and
>   complete later on; **the array types at those two points (“array of
>   unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types**.

But, as @MattMcNabb said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967060/is-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-unknow-size-incomplete/25967260?noredirect=1#comment40694455_25967260) earlier these declaration declared variables of the same type. And it's natural and logical, but what the Standard means in there is not clear.

Comment: If I wanted to be humorous I would write '*just use an int vector*'

Comment: wouldn't it help if this were tagged with language-lawyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted the following is not allowed:

```
extern int a[5];
int a[6];
```

anyway there's a catch for

```
extern int a[];
int a[6];
```

§3.5/10

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types
>   specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, **except that declarations
>   for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array
>   bound (8.3.4)**. A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

That's actually an exception to the rule. This won't work if the type is different

```
extern int arr[];
float arr[6];
```

Comment: So that exception is just for the rule from 3.9/6, is it?

Comment: That's what I was referring, yes.