# Surprising completion of unknown array size typedef in C (gcc) to a known array size type

Tags: arrays, c, incomplete-type, completion

I've occurred an interesting situation – **completing an incomplete array-size typedef** to a known array size, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct hi_
{
  int a, s;
} hi[];

int main() {
    hi there = { {3,7}, {1,5} };
    hi there2 = { {11,17} };

    printf("«1» 1/a: %i, 1/s: %i\n2/a:%i 2/s:%i\n", there[0].a, there[0].s, there[1].a, there[1].s);
    printf("«2» 1/a: %i, 1/s: %i\n", there2[0].a, there2[0].s);

// Output:
// «1» 1/a: 3, 1/s: 7
// 2/a:1 2/s:5
// «2» 1/a: 11, 1/s: 17

}
```

I'm little surprised, because in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25967495/3246357) it is quite strongly supported that such type "**cannot be completed**". So, why and how does this work?

Comment: As an analogy: `int a[]= {1,2,3};` declares an array of size 3 ints and initializes it. It is the same with your code. The type is complete, only its size is not given in the typedef.

Answer (score 2):

The `typedef` in the question defines `hi` to be an array (of unknown size).

The answer you cite does not say an incomplete array cannot be completed. It says a pointer to an incomplete array cannot be completed. It quotes the standard:

> … The type of a pointer to array of unknown size, or of a type defined by a `typedef` declaration to be an array of unknown size, cannot be completed.

There is a grammatical error here (see below, the “of a type” should be “to a type”), but the answer states the intended meaning:

> Read in context, it's clearly saying that a "pointer to array of unknown bound of `T`" can't be "completed" into a "pointer to array of N `T`"

The grammatical error is that the “of a type defined by a `typedef` declaration to be an array of unknown size” is intended, by the “or” to be an alternative to “array of unknown size”. Thus, replacing “array unknown size” with “of a type…” would yield “The type of a pointer to of a type defined by a `typedef` declaration to be an array of unknown size…” So that “to of” is grammatically incorrect, not what was intended.

The sentence could have been:

> The type of a pointer to an array of unknown size or to a type defined by a `typedef` to be an array of unknown size cannot be completed.

As for why the type is completed, C 2018 6.7.9 22 says:

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its initializer list.

Thus, `there` and `there2` are arrays of unknown size (because the `hi` identifier is an alias for such an array), so they are completed by the initialization.

Had you instead declared a pointer to `hi`, `hi *p;`, there would be no way to complete it, even with initialization.

Comment: `hi p[3];` would complete the array but without initialization? Or is this invalid because the array braces are part of the typedef?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: `hi` is an array, so `hi something[3]` would be an array of 3 arrays. (And that violates a rule that the elements of an array must be complete, which `hi` is not.)

Comment: So _except_ by initialization, there is no way to specify the size of a `hi`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: You can allocate memory and create a `hi` by writing one to the memory. In the terms of the C standard, that creates an object of that type in memory. But you would not have an identifier for it, just a pointer to the incomplete `hi` type. I cannot think of any way other than initialization to indicate the size. Of course, one does not need to provide the initializers; you could do `hi there = { [99] = 0 };`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I thought of another way. You can define a structure with a last member of `hi` type. Then it is a flexible array member, and it has as many elements as space allows. So that defines the size. If you create one with automatic or static storage duration (rather than allocated), the compiler just allocates its base size for the structure. That may allow create some elements (due to padding caused by other structure elements) but will often create just zero elements. In this special case, the array acts as if it had one element, but you may not use it (C 2018 6.7.2.1 18).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Then there is the question of what happens of you define a union with one huge member and the other member being a structure with a `hi` last member. Are you allowed to use the extra space for the flexible array member?